# How to check if two memory modules are being used with dual channel?

Tags: memory, ddr3, dual-channel

I have two 1333 DDR3 memory modules with different brands. I wonder if they can be used in a dual channel setup. How can I check that?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

download CPU-z over here: http://www.cpuid.com/softwares/cpu-z.html , once you have got it downloaded open it up and go to the memory tab at the top. Once you are there you will see a box that says channels: [AMOUNT OF CHANNELS] . That's it.

I hope I helped :)

Comment: it tells the number of channels available/being used. Does it tell whether the ram is actually working in "dual channel memory mode", that is twice the bandwidth.

Answer (score 14):

This information is usually available on boot or inside the bios.

[image: AMI Bios]
[image: AMI Bios]
[image: Award Bios]

Comment: i dont see this information on my ddr4 desktop and laptop uefi interfaces. where else can i see it.

Comment: As the accepted answer says, you can also install CPU-Z to check for dual-channel mode: https://techwiser.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/12/dual-channel-cpu-z-ram.png

Answer (score 1):

You can also check if the Dual channel mode is active by using [AIDA64 Extreme Edition](http://www.aida64.com/downloads/a64xe), by going in Motherboard/Chipset on left menu and accessing the Memory Controller information. If the Active Mode is Dual Channel (128 bits), then your memory is operating on dual channel mode