# What is the right memory module configuration for my system?

Tags: memory

> For maximum performance, split pairs of DIMMs across slots that use different memory channels. If you're on a budget, this means you'll get better performance out of, say, two 4GB DIMMS than a single 8GB DIMM. Then again, the real-life performance gain is minimal, and you're limiting your ability to increase memory in the future.   - [PCWorld](http://www.pcworld.com/article/2691193/do-the-research-before-you-upgrade-your-ram.html)

My machine is 8540w with the following result for memory modules output from hwinfo32 program:

> Memory Devices
>
> Physical Memory Array

```
Array Location: System board
Array Use:  System memory
Error Detecting Method: None
Memory Capacity:    16777216 KBytes
Memory Devices: 4
```

> > Memory Device

```
Total Width:    64 bits
Data Width: 64 bits
Device Size:    2048 MBytes
Device Form Factor: SODIMM
Device Locator: Top-Slot 1(top)
Bank Locator:   BANK 0
Device Type:    DDR3 SDRAM
Device Type Detail: Synchronous
Memory Speed:   1333 MHz
Manufacturer:   Elpida
Serial Number:  D33A3074
Part Number:    EBJ21UE8BDS0-DJ-F
Asset Tag:  Unknown
```

> > Memory Device

```
Total Width:    0 bits
Data Width: 0 bits
Device Size:    0 MBytes
Device Form Factor: DIMM
Device Locator: Bottom-Slot 2(left)
Bank Locator:   BANK 3
Device Type:    Unknown
Device Type Detail: 
Manufacturer:   Unknown
Serial Number:  Unknown
Part Number:    Unknown
Asset Tag:  Unknown
```

> > Memory Device

```
Total Width:    0 bits
Data Width: 0 bits
Device Size:    0 MBytes
Device Form Factor: DIMM
Device Locator: Bottom-Slot 1(right)
Bank Locator:   BANK 2
Device Type:    Unknown
Device Type Detail: 
Manufacturer:   Unknown
Serial Number:  Unknown
Part Number:    Unknown
Asset Tag:  Unknown
```

> > Memory Device

```
Total Width:    64 bits
Data Width: 64 bits
Device Size:    2048 MBytes
Device Form Factor: SODIMM
Device Locator: Top-Slot 2(under)
Bank Locator:   BANK 1
Device Type:    DDR3 SDRAM
Device Type Detail: Synchronous
Memory Speed:   1333 MHz
Manufacturer:   Elpida
Serial Number:  E03A3074
Part Number:    EBJ21UE8BDS0-DJ-F
Asset Tag:  Unknown
```

Having opened the expansion memory bay for the laptop, I found both slots empty. Also, the Windows Resource Manager shows memory configuration as follows:
[image]

Given that my [Core i7-720QM](http://ark.intel.com/products/43122/Intel-Core-i7-720QM-Processor-6M-Cache-1_60-GHz) Processor specification says that the system supports 8 GB of memory at most, and the fact that there are two empty memory slots under the laptop, which of the following memory configurations should I consider to upgrade my system memory?
- 2×2GB memory modules
- 1×4GB memory module (installed in one of the slots)

Also, which memory speed should I opt for? 1600 or 1333 MHz

Comment: You currently have 4GB installed.  So the largest module you could use is a single 4 GB module or two 2 GB modules.

Comment: I would appreciate it if down-voters leave a comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

4x2GB 1333mhz DDR3. Two dual-channel pairs. Keep original 2x2GB and add new matched pair as upgrade.

It is a mere laptop, not high-performance machine (anymore), so your main performance hit will be mass storage anyway. Especially if your system drive is classic HDD. (Consider SSHD or SSD).

1. Ram speed: 1333mhz. [Intel Ark](http://ark.intel.com/products/43122/Intel-Core-i7-720QM-Processor-6M-Cache-1_60-GHz) says: DDR3 1066/1333. You won't make use of anything faster, and instead will need to hope it will throttle down correctly to supported speeds. As you already have 1333mhz modules getting 1066 would be a waste.
2. Module size: consider upgrading with matching 2x2GB unless it won't make any sense price-wise. You will get extra redundancy and tiny boost from dual-channel. (depending on benchmark, results vary between ~3% to ~15% in real life use). Remember to check which slots are channeled together.
3. Use same or as similar as possible memory modules for dual-channel pair. Your original memory modules are already matching. [Long story](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multi-channel_memory_architecture#Dual-channel_architecture) short, memory modules needs to be of same size and speed (automatic downclocking **should** happen if speed varies, but may fail in edge cases), hence using same model is safe bet. Different pairs (usually) work fine.

Note: Remember to [check if dual-channel works](https://superuser.com/questions/426445/how-to-check-if-two-memory-modules-are-being-used-with-dual-channel). I would suggest checking it before upgrading to confirm original two memory modules are in dual channel, if not, you might need to switch them around ports, which would require disassembly (thus most probably voiding warranty, if any remains).

Hint: Shop for 2x2GB, not 2GB, it will yield matched pairs

Tip: [You can replace your optical (CD/DVD) drive with another disk](http://blog.superuser.com/2011/05/04/best-of-both-worlds-putting-an-ssd-in-your-optical-bay/).

Comment: Do you mean my system will fail if I use 1600 MHz modules?

Comment: @JasonStack It **should** work properly. Or it **could** fail. It could be even so only one pair, old or new, would work at a time. Matching speeds is simply safer bet.

Comment: Both halves of this answer are wrong. The first half is wrong because you can make use of faster memory even if you can't support its clock speed (the faster clock speed turns into faster timing). The second half is wrong because it ignores the fact that he already has 5GB installed.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz 1. Its 5GB of [commited memory](http://superuser.com/questions/836286/window-8-ram-usage-committed-memory), physical RAM size is in top right corner of Win8/10 task manager. 2. Mixing different latency sticks falls under category ["**should** work, **could** fail"](http://superuser.com/questions/52340/is-it-safe-to-use-ram-sticks-with-different-frequencies)

Comment: @PTwr Still, if he has 4GB already, why would you think adding 2x2GB would give him dual channel? And if you were trying to avoid sticks with different latencies, why didn't your answer say anything about latency at all?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz 1. His machine seems to have two pairs of slots, one internal, and one external under laptop (for upgrading without voiding warranty), also [HP says it supports dual-channel](http://h20564.www2.hp.com/hpsc/doc/public/display?docId=emr_na-c02030608). 2. Good idea about latency, will edit to clarify.

Comment: I know that. However, your answer seems to assume his system has no memory.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/34540/discussion-between-ptwr-and-david-schwartz).